# symfony url redirect : Some mandatory parameters are missing

Tags: symfony, routes

My symfony project handle dynamic subdomains.

```
my-project_back:
    resource: "@MyProjectBackOfficeBundle/Controller/"
    host: "{client}.my-project.com"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
```

As you can see I prefix all the backOffice route with /admin.

If a client reach the website without /admin I want to redirect him.

```
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /admin
        permanent: true
```

It works but I always get this error when I'm not logged in :

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("client") to generate a URL for
>   route "_myproject_login".

Maybe it's caused by the double redirection.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: you should look at the doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html 
You will find exemple on how to pass parameters

Comment: Sorry but I still not see the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, "/" was missing after "admin" in path

```
 root:
     path: /
     defaults:
         _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
         path: /admin/
         permanent: true
```